# Creating Database in MongoDB and Inserting data from file

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb, database

I just configured Mongo Db on my system.
What is the difference between `collection and Database` in Mongo DB,
I did db.help() to see different functions.
But I couldn't find any function to add create db,create table or column etc
I have a csv file that i want to load in Mongo DB.
Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MongoDB you don't have to specifically create the database or collections. Just by calling one will create it if it's not available. You also don't create columns like you do in SQL, fields are dynamic and you can have many different fields in your documents. As for importing a csv, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686500/how-to-use-mongoimport-to-import-csv)

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you know the basic difference between SQL and NOSQL.

If your still new then check this link out. 
[here!](http://www.sitepoint.com/sql-vs-nosql-differences/)

---

And to answer your question:

> Question 1: What is the difference between collection and a database ?
>   A collection in mongoDB is equivalent to tables in the Sql world.

In SQL(MYSQL,....) : Database --> Tables -- Rows&columns.

In NOSQL(MongoDB,....): Database ---> collection ----> documents(JSON in most cases).

> Question2 : How to create database and collections and insert data.

Unlike SQL databases where you must pre-define a schema before you insert data into each row,column. Mongodb has a flexible schema in which it is essential for the concept for mongodb.

#### Create new database

use databaseName

ex: use foo

#### db.databaseName.CollectionName.insert({"":""})

What will happen is the use statement will search for a database with that name and if it doesn't find it will create on. Then you will have to insert you new collection and your good to go!

> Question 3 : How to load a cvs to mongodb.

Check This link [here!](https://docs.compose.io/importing-exporting/from-csv.html)

> Quick tip:
>   Check the link [here!](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/). It has valuable information if you are coming from the SQL universe and would like a fast way to query in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

A collection in mongoDb is just the same as a table in a relational sql database. To create a database in mongoDB just type `use exampleDB`. Also you create collections on the fly while you insert documents in the collection. The MongoDB documents explains this very well, I would recommend going through them here [mongoDB CRUD Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/#create-operations)