# unexpected identifier error while bulk insert into mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a json file and am trying to insert in bulk to mongodb
I do
`mongoimport --host localhost --db testdb --collection testdbjson --username user --      password pass --type json --file /home/pet/mng/json_test.json`
It gives the following error 
    `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongodb importig and exporting to csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679398/mongodb-importig-and-exporting-to-csv)

Comment: are u running mongoimport from the console (right)? or are u running the command in the mongo shell (wrong)?

Answer (score 3):

the document [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) the correct syntax

```
mongoimport -host 127.0.0.1 -port 27017 -u user -p pass -collection testdbjson --db testdb --file /home/pet/mng/json_test.json
```

or

```
mongoimport -host 127.0.0.1:27017 -u user -p pass -collection testdbjson --db testdb --file /home/pet/mng/json_test.json
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same error now - I figured it out. I think you have connected to your mongo instance on mongolab first before you wanted to import.
You must not connect to mongolab first - disconnect by typing in "exit" in the shell to get back to command prompt. Then issue the mongoimport command again, the import should work this time.