# Import csv file in Mongod Db 2.4

Tags: mongodb, csv

I have tried various commands for importing csv file into mongodb but most are giving errors."unexpected identifier"

```
mongoimport -h host:port -d experimental2 -c <collection> -u <user> -p <password> --file <input .csv file> --type csv --headerline

mongoimport -h localhost --port 27017 -d test -c forcasting --type csv --file ~/Desktop/forecasting.csv

mongoimport -h piyushl  --port 27017 -d test -c forcasting --type csv --file ~/Desktop/forecasting.csv

mongoimport -h localhost:27017 -d test -c forcasting -u Piyushl --file forecasting --type csv --headerline
```

But nothing seems to work.

Comment: what delimiter you have in your csv ? comma or some thing else

Comment: if you ran the command there must have been some output, please share that we can help from there on.

Comment: Could you also check if there are special identifiers or if file contains values in different unicode.

Comment: Microsoft Office Excel Comma Separated Values File. NOte the output is "unexpected identifier" as mentioned above.The file does  not have different unicode.

Comment: Does this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679398/mongodb-importig-and-exporting-to-csv

Comment: Unexpected identifier means that there is something invalid (from a mongoimport perspective) within your CSV file. Without seeing the full CSV file we will be unable to give you a definitive answer as to what the issue is.