# how to import csv file in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a csv file containing following data and want to import it in mongodb

```
ID;"AdmissionID";"SeatNo";"RegistrationNo";"ResultDate";"ResultStatusId"
1;12;"2323";"23";07-05-2013;1
2;23;"35";"32";10-05-2013;5
```

this data is to be imported to mongodb 2.2. I'm using following command:

```
mongoimport -d test -c exam --type csv --headerline <f:\exam.csv
```

when used i get following error

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (shell):1
```

please help me to find out the error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686500/how-to-use-mongoimport-to-import-csv

Comment: Please [Check Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/) , this link give you the idea

Comment: Also, as the parameter suggests, it's supposed to be a comma-separated-value file, not semi-colons.

Comment: your file is not "comma seperate" rather it is semi comma seperated (;).
change it to Comma Seperate using excel if using windows or use sed command in UNIX and then import it.

Answer (score 9):

This should do the trick easily. More [HERE](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/).

```
 mongoimport -d mydb -c collectionName --type csv --file myfile.csv --headerline
```

Your problem is the `<f:\exam.csv` bit, which is not properly escaped by the way it looks

```
> --headerline
> If using “--type csv” or “--type tsv,” use the first line as field names. Otherwise, mongoimport will import the first line as a distinct
> document.
```

Comment: How passing the file as an argument instead of reading it from the standard input should help?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this line of code

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongoimport -d pravin -c FOC --type csv
--file D:\Script\ImportData\FOC.csv --headerline
2016-08-10T15:42:38.685+0530    connected to: localhost`enter code here`
2016-08-10T15:42:38.758+0530    imported 13 documents
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved by opening the .csv file in Excel (File -> Options -> advanced) then unchecking the box "uses system separation" and then removing the comma from the box below and then saving again in .csv.

[image]

So there will not be any commas in the .csv file and the formatting of JSON in MongoDB will be right.

Answer (score 0):

Run mongoimport from the system command line, not the mongo shell.

Ref - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/