# read data from excel file c# to mongodb database

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, excel-2007

My application needs to read data from an excel file and stocks it in MongoDB database. I am using .Net and c# for development.I am using Excel 2007 , MongoDB 3.2 and visual studio 2015 version.
Any idea to access excel file, i need your help please.

This is my code

```
 public void Open_readXLS()
    {

         Excel.Workbook workbook;
         Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
         Optioncontext ctx = new Optioncontext();

    string filePath = @"C:\Users\user PC\Desktop\ finale\Euro_Dollar_Call_Options.xlsx";
     workbook = new Excel.Workbook(filePath); 
     worksheet = workbook.Sheets.GetByName("Feuil1");

    for (ushort i = 0; i <= worksheet.Rows.LastRow; i++)
    {
         option.type_option= worksheet.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
         option.type_currency=  worksheet.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    }
    ctx.Option.InsertOne(option);
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us your research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of achieving this. The simplest would be to save your Excel as a CSV-file for further processing; you can do this in Excel by selecting "Save As" in the "File" menu and then changing the file-ending to CSV. Once you have done this you can use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) to import its contents - no need for C# code in this scenario. You may have to adjust the contents of your CSV so that it fits the structure that is expected by mongoimport; here is a SO post about just that [How to use mongoimport to import csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686500/how-to-use-mongoimport-to-import-csv).