# Mean Stack - storing of data

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I want to make website on books using mean stack so I want to store contents of books now I don't know where I have to store all those content in database or somewhere else.

Comment: You store it in the database, MongoDB, which is the M in MEAN. What is unclear?!

Comment: You can use this yeoman generator to quickly get started with the MEAN stack. If you generate a project you can see how the database is being used. https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to import a CSV file. MongoDB can import CSV files directly:

> In the following example, mongoimport imports the csv formatted data
>   in the /opt/backups/contacts.csv file into the collection contacts in
>   the users database on the MongoDB instance running on the localhost
>   port numbered 27017.
>
> Specifying --headerline instructs mongoimport to determine the name of
>   the fields using the first line in the CSV file.

```
mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --headerline --file /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

Source:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

See also:
[How to use mongoimport to import csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686500/how-to-use-mongoimport-to-import-csv)